# what is sni_endpoint and how to add it in heroku

Tags: api, heroku, dns, custom-domain

I am trying to add a custom domain to my Heroku app but after adding the custom domain the given Dns target is now working. Whenever I try to visit my Dns target link, It says that **synthetic-stonecrop-p4oa311n91p2gcgbqide0d1b.herokudns.com didn’t send any data.** I guess the procedure of adding a new domain is updated but heroku did not mentioned it in there official docs. I want to know what this `sni_endpoint` is and how to configure it for my app. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks !

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Error: requires params: sni_endpoint. I hope we get solutions to this problem. Heroku is not giving the format of "heroku domains:add" with the option of sni_endpoint.

Comment: @Djesu Try to add domain from the heroku website and not from the heroku CLI. I am able to add the domain from the heroku website.

Comment: Any update on this?